# Arduino Uno Pin D9 Voltage

Tags: module, embedded, arduino, gprs

I have a Shield extension module.
In Arduino Example, It can use D9 to PowerOn by software instead of trigger

But I use BeagleBone or others borad now, so I need to know
"How much voltage will D9 output"

thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Digital pins of an Arduino are directly driven by the port pins of the ATmega 328p (or older) processor.  This is a CMOS device, so the output will, under light load, drive fairly close to the supply voltage, which on an unmodified UNO with an in-spec supply, would typically be 5v.  Reference the ATmega328p data sheet if you want a more precise answer.

Almost all logic device have a `V(IH)` - input voltage to reliably be a logic "1" - which is much less than the voltage of corresponding outputs when driving a "1" - the difference is called the *noise margin*.  Depending on the technology, `V(IH)` could be as low as 2v, ranging up to perhaps 2/3 of the receiver's supply voltage.

Your BeagleBone likely has a 3.3V (or perhaps even lower) supply for it I/O banks.  A 3.3V-referenced "1" output may be marginal in comparison to the `V(IH)` of a 5V-referenced receiver's input pin.  Some 5V parts are specifically designed with a low `V(IH)` in order to be reliably driven by 3.3V parts.  Others would not be reliably driven according to the specs, but may in practice tend to work under good conditions, but there is obviously a risk in depending on that for anything but a temporary experiment.

There are many approaches to building *level translators* which can be used to reliably drive a 5V part with a high `V(IH)` from a 3.3v output, for example using IC buffers, bipolar transistors, or FETs.  Getting into those in detail would probably be better covered at http://electronics.stackexchange.com - if you search there you will likely find it has already been covered a number of times.

Note that depending on what your shield actually is, it might itself actually be made of 3.3V parts, and so have no need for 5V inputs at all.  If made with 3.3V parts, for use with a 5V UNO it would have to either use 3.3V parts rated to tolerate 5V inputs, or there might be a circuit to reduce the 5V input from the UNO to 3.3V for the onboard parts.  That would be especially true of devices more technically sophisticated than the UNO, such as things like radio chipsets.

Comment: so...Actually, I need a singal VH is 5V, is it?

Comment: No, the `V(IH)` input requirement is going to be notably less than 5V, but how much less could only be learned by examining the shield and researching the parts found on it.

Comment: So...I need to try it. But in spec, its need may be less than 5V?